# Emacs vc-svn cannot work with svn 1.7.3, always prompt that this file is not under version control

Tags: svn, emacs

I used emacs23.4 with svn 1.4.2 and vc-svn on CentOS 5.5 for a long time and there is nothing wrong.

Yesterday, after I rebuilt my svn to 1.7.3, I could not use vc-svn in emacs anymore: I tried to ediff files except those are under repository root, but got only one feedback that: this file is not under version control.

But I can still use svn in bash out of emacs normally.

I found that, unlike svn 1.4.2 (create .svn under every folder of the repository) , svn 1.7.3 only creates .svn under repository root. Maybe it is the problem.

So how should I do to  get emacs vc-svn work? Any reply will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Although Subversion 1.7 has been out for a few months, because of the major changes in the way it works, a lot of programs still have not caught up with it yet. We still use Subversion 1.6 at our work because of the tools issues. I believe the next release of Emacs will work with Subversion 1.7.

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply, maybe I should change subversion back to 1.6, or wait for the next release of emacs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [EmacsWiki](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/SubVersion)

> Emacs 24 supports Subversion 1.7, but Emacs 23 does not. If you want to use Subversion 1.7 on Emacs 23, you can use [vc-svn17.el](https://github.com/buzztaiki/vc-svn17-el/blob/master/vc-svn17.el) for this purpose.

I haven't tried it (yet) myself.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Emacs 24?  It's in pre-release now and quite stable.